# Using RestTemplate to get a list of XML objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm wondering how, calling an external API service to get a list of object mapped by my class.

This is what the XML looks like

```xml
<ArrayOfObject>
    <Object>
        <id></id>
        <name></name>
        <var1></var1>
        <var2></var2>
        <var3></var3>
    </Object>
    <Object>
       <id></id>
       <name></name>
       <var1></var1>
       <var2></var2>
       <var3></var3>
   </Object>
  
   ...

</ArrayOfObject>
```

I'm trying to get only the id and name so i've tried to map in my class only theese two fields (tried even with all of them but didn't work, not expecting that):

```java
public class Object{
    public String id, name;
    
    public Object() {}
    public Object(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name= name;
    }


    public String getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

and wrap it into

```java
public class ArrayOfObject {
    
    private List<Object> objects;
    
    public ArrayOfObject () {
        object = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    
    public List<Object> getObjects() {return objects;}
    public void setObjects(List<Object> objects) {
    this.objects = objects;
    }   
}
```

So now this is what my controller looks like

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class RestCall {

    @GetMapping("/objects")
    public List<Object> getObject(){
        final String uri = "";
        
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
        
    ArrayOfObject result = rt.getForObject(uri, ArrayOfObject.class);
    return result.getObjects();
    }
}
```

When it comes time to test the results are:

```
org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class it.me.model.ArrayOfObject] and content type [text/xml;charset=utf-8]
```

Did i do something wrong or am i missing something?

**Moved** to a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74462594/using-resttemplate-to-get-a-list-of-xml-objects-gives-back-an-empty-list) and **Solved**

Comment: Please *ever avoid* re-using class names from `java.lang.*`!!! (`Object` is the worse possible class name in java! (which do you mean??))

Comment: Add annoations for JAXB so it knows what to map to what.

Comment: I'm not using object just named that for the example @xerx593

Comment: which JAXB annotation you mean @M.Deinum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're using Jackson for (de)serialization... Did you add jackson xml module?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And add *@JsonIgnoreProperties* to your pojo to omit unmapped fields

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class Object{
```

For deserializing to list try...

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
private List<Object> object; // same name as in xml
```

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization

Comment: I did it now but comes back with an empty list meanwhile from the browser it doesn't. And no i'm pretty sure i'm not using any serialization, at least consciously.

Comment: @matt added hint for list

Comment: thanks, but still empty, i'll try to read better baeldung but is there something i can log to get what's going on? Should i set spring loggin level to a more specific one?

Comment: try with empty default constructor  `public ArrayOfObject () {}`

Comment: and ajust log level for package com.fasterxml.jackson

Comment: i've tried with an empty constructor, with and without the field initialization, i've tried omitting the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` but stil empty maybe i'll try open, if you don't have any other ideas, a new question thank you @MarcStroebel

Comment: didn't saw nothing from the `com.fasterxml.jackson ` may be not logged